# Can I bake bread in a Bread machine with Swad gluten free flour?

Tags: bread, dough, gluten-free

I’ve tried a few different recipes but they aren’t rising!  Any help will be appreciated. The best recipe so far is:

- 1.5 cup Swad gluten free flour (amaranth, sorghum, millet, rice, corn, water chestnut, soybean, arrowroot mixture)
- 3tbsp sugar
- 1tsp salt
- 2tsp psyllium husk
- 2.125 tsp yeast
- .5 cup warm unsweetened almond milk
- .25 cup olive oil
- 3 eggs (whites whipped to peaks)
- 1tsp apple cider vinegar

I put all the liquids in first, then dry, then yeast, and set it for quick bread. I read that if you do not have a gluten free setting on your machine to use quick bread setting.

What am I doing wrong? How do I make this dough rise?

Comment: Is this a recipe that you know works as a yeast bread? How do you get 2.125 tsp yeast?

Comment: I got the recipe online. It called for 3 cups of rice flour and 2 teaspoons of yeast. I tried it with my swag flour and It turned out very heavy and hard. No bread is that heavy so  I lowered the amount of flour and reduced the milk and left everything else the same and it was better. I also whipped the egg whites which always helped my muffins be fluffier. I did add the 1/8 teaspoon yeast also.

Comment: I figured out a fluffy recipe for this flour but the only problem is the loaf is really small. If I double my recipe, yeast and all, would the loaf still rise as much?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid your chances aren't good.

Wheat bread with yeast, gluten-free bread, and wheat quickbread are made in different ways. The wheat bread with yeast is ideally made with several cycles of kneading and rising. A gf bread is not kneaded, just mixed, and then has to rise once. The quickbread is also not kneaded, but it has to be baked immediately, without a rising time. So, if you want to make any of these with a bread machine, you have to use a program that was engineered to deliver the needed conditions.

If your machine has no gluten-free program, then it is unlikely that any of the other cycles matches the conditions needed for gluten-free bread. There is some likelihood that some of the programs that you have can match some kind of recipe such that the result is not inedibly terrible, but discovering such a combination would require a lot of experimentation, and the result will only be valid for your exact breadmaker model. Also, the result is unlikely to be especially good.

In the end, if you are making the bread frequently, it may be worth investing in a new breadmaker, after researching which one has a decent gf-program (and then you will have to find out which recipes work - which may or may not use the exact flour mixture you have). If this is a one-off occasion, just buy the bread from a store. GF-bread is very finicky, and probably not worth the learning curve if you won't make it regularly.

Comment: Thank you! I’m off to buy a gf machine! I’ll let you know how it goes!

Comment: I purchased a bread machine with a gluten free option and I’m a little confused. From what i read they don’t think gf bread would rise 3 times and should only let it rise once. The gf option on the bread machine does have the bread rising three times. The machine also has a dough and bake function that i could start after it rises once?  Does anybody know how many times whole grain gf bread should rise? (I know I’m being very optimistic that it will rise at all). Thank you!

Comment: The number of rises is determined by the recipe. If you are using the gf option on the bread machine, you should use the recipe that came in the machine's booklet. If you want to hand-make dough from a recipe intended for making by hand, but mix and bake it in the machine, then you should let it rise as many times as your recipe prescribes. But in general, I have trouble imagining a gf bread turning out well if it is punched down/mixed between rises.

Comment: I figured out a fluffy recipe for this flour but the only problem is the loaf is really small. If I double my recipe, yeast and all, would the loaf still rise as much?

Comment: @Boo Glad to hear it worked for you! I have very little experience with bread machines, so I am not entirely sure what will happen if you double it. By hand, doubling is no problem at all, as long as all amounts are changed proportionally. By machine, there is a small chance that the timing will be off - e.g. that the larger mass needs a longer rising time. But in your situation, the best you can do is to try it and see if it works well.

Comment: I can stop this machine and let it rise for a longer time. But I’d be using 4 teaspoons of yeast and 6 eggs!  Maybe I’ll try 1.5%. If I left the recipe as is would adding more yeast help it to rise more ? I did read somewhere that it can have a negative effect if there is too much? Thank you for your help!